# web service with glassfish v3

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3

I am using JSF 2.0, Spring, Hibernate and GlassFish v3 server and I need to make webservice and I am totally new to webservice can anyone suggest what kind of webservice I should go for...

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague and the mentioned technologies don't have much to do with web services. Anyway, my recommendation would be to use JAX-WS which is supported by GlassFish out of the box (the implementation is provided by Metro, the WS stack in GlassFish).

Here are a few tutorials:

- [Building Web Services with JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) in the Java EE 6 Tutorial
- [Introducing JAX-WS 2.0 With the Java SE 6 Platform, Part 1](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)
- [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)
- [Developing JAX-WS Web Service Clients](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean jax-ws (soap based) or jax-rs (rest based). if this is the case http://www.rekk.de/bloggy/2008/java-webservices-relationship-of-jax-ws-jax-rs-metro-and-jersey/